# How to make DIV element opaque

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div at the top of my site which is 100% wide and in a absolute and fixed position. The code for it is like:

```
div.header{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

Now everything in that works, but when users scroll down the site content appears behind this. Is there a way that I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: You shouldn't be giving this element two `position:` properties.. either or..

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted to suggest that `div.header` isn't fully opaque.

Comment: Your question is also misleading, do you want this div to be opaque, or are you just trying to prevent overlap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A div element that needs to be displayed on front should have a higher `z-index` value than the element that needs to be behind.

eg.

```
div.header{
....
....
z-index:9999;
}

div.normal{
....
....
z-index:9998;
}
```

On my [website](http://www.philipstarritt.com) I have a div footer that always appears at the bottom. I use the following code - It may come in handy in the future or for someone searching for a similar query.

```
#bottom
{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: rgb(30,122,212); 
    border-top:3px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    -moz-box-sadow: 0 0 10px white; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px white;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! finally someone understood my question :)

This method worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: @JoshuaDempsey It would help if you understood what you were asking. The div isn't transparent at all. Other content was showing on top of it, not from underneath it.

Comment: You are right I guess. It had the effect of being transparent, but I didn't know it was called as I didn't know of "z-index."

Answer (score 6):

remove `position: fixed;`

it should be like

```
div.header{
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

If you want to make it fixed than remove `position:absolute`. both will not work together.

you have `position:absolute` and `fixed` both together, but `fixed` will override the position because it is after absolute.

Now if you want to appear any element above of other and it has a position: absolute or fixed you can use `z-index`, heigher z-index element will cover up the lower z-index element.

Answer (score 0):

It is a silly question. Just remove the `position: fixed;` property from your class.

Comment: But I want it to stay in the same position. It's just content keeps appearing behind it.

Comment: Try this: position:absolute; if not working send me the full code.